# Error while loading a huggingface transformer model to perform text classification

Tags: python, attributeerror, arabic, huggingface-transformers, text-classification

I'm training a transformer model by regular training as described in [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1P9iQHtUH5KUbTVtp8B4-AopZzEEPE0lw?usp=sharing) to classify the questions with their expected answer class.

After training the model, I want to see the predictions for some questions, so I wrote the following code:

```
from transformers import pipeline,AutoModel, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer

model_name = 'aubmindlab/bert-base-arabertv02'

arabert_model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('/gdrive/MyDrive/LabelModel')

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

text = "أين وقعت غزوة بدر؟"
#{'كيان': 0, 'تقريري': 1, 'حدث': 2, 'رقم': 3, 'عاقل': 4, 'موقع': 5, 'وصف': 6}

pipe = pipeline(model=arabert_model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

pipe(text)
```

First, it gave me this error:

```
OSError: Error no file named pytorch_model.bin, tf_model.h5, model.ckpt.index or flax_model.msgpack found in directory /gdrive/MyDrive/LabelModel.
```

Then I solved this problem by renaming the training_args.bin file in my directory to pytorch_model.bin as suggested in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62961627/oserror-error-no-file-named-pytorch-model-bin-tf-model-h5-model-ckpt-in).

After that, another error exists:

```
AttributeError: 'TrainingArguments' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in the space of Google Drive, it deleted the pytorch.bin file. So there is no error in the code related to the bin file.